# Is right to say "when he was come down from the mountain"?

Tags: passive-voice

> When he was come down from the mountain, great multitudes followed
>   him.

This is the quote from KJV Bible. I am doubted why to say "he was come down". I felt "he came down" is more proper grammatically.

Be + Verb in pp form is usually a passive voice which seems irrelevant in this context. However, I did hear a lot native English speakers say 'he was come down', 'are you agree with me?', etc. Is this usage correct?

Comment: That is an archaic usage. I'd advise you not to use it unless you want to also wear period costume and appear in a fair somewhere.

Comment: It's archaic, but the modern equivalent is not "when he came down" but "when he had come down".